# Measurement of motor wattage

Tags: power, dc-motor

I have a old motor which has no printing information outside. How to measure its input wattage. Its burning on 14v  3.0A source[image]

Comment: So it is already burnt? So why do you care what *was* the wattage?

Comment: A motor is a converter from electrical to mechanical power. So it doesn't have a fixed "wattage". It has a wattage under certain conditions (e.g. free running, or in maximum power point etc). But: looking at your motor, these were never overly well spec'ed, and now that it's burnt, it's time to wonder what kind of motor power you actually need.

Comment: Just a photo tip - when sending a photo like this put something in the photo to indicate scale e.g. a coin. That way we can estimate the physical size. Judging by the 'grain' flecks this motor is quite small.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, it still working

Comment: @JImDearden Ok, I'll provide such type of photo

Comment: @JImDearden It is about 3 inch long and its radius about 1 inch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extrapolate from some measurements.  The physical size will give you some idea of how much power the motor can dissipate itself without frying.  Look at specs of other motors that are about the same size and overall construction.

You say it's "burning" on 14 V.  So don't do that.  Use a variable supply and slowly crank up the voltage until you think the motor is running as fast as it should.  That may be hard to guess, but it should not be dissipating significant power then.  If it gets really hot at 14 V, then don't give it more than 12 V.  Maybe it's a 9 V or 6 V motor.  Does it seem to run "fast" unloaded at 9 V or 6 V?  When slowly ramping up from 0, at what voltage does it start spinning with no mechanical load?

Once you think you have the operating voltage, find the current draw at that voltage with the shaft held fixed.  That is the stall current.  That times the voltage is the worst case power the motor will dissipate at that voltage.  Also measure the unloaded current at the same voltage, and the spin speed under those conditions if you can.  That will give you some idea of the efficiency and the internal generator constant.

Give it the maximum voltage you determined and hold it there with the shaft frozen for a little while.  Keep monitoring the temperature.  If it seems to be getting hot fast, turn it off.  If it seems to be able to take it long enough to reach equilibrium temperature, then you've found everything you need to know.

If the motor gets too hot, then either your top rated voltage guess was too high, or this motor isn't intended to be run at stall indefinitely.  Use as appropriate to what you find.